# How to justify $\frac14(n^2(n+1)^2)+\frac14(4(n+1)^3) = \frac14(n+1)^2(n^2+4(n+1))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does my lecturer go from :

$$ \frac {n^2(n+1)^2} {4} + \frac {4(n+1)^3} {4} \text{ to }  \frac {(n+1)^2} {4} \times [n^2+4(n+1)] $$

I can understand that $$ \frac {n^2(n+1)^2} {4} = \frac {(n+1)^2} {4}\times n^2 $$

But I'm not sure how he can legally multiply $n^2+4(n+1) \text{ by } \frac {(n+1)^2} {4} $.

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE! For future questions, please try to make the title of your question more informative (I've done so for you now). E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\frac{4(n+1)^3}{4}$ you can extract $4(n+1)$, i.e.

$$\frac{4(n+1)^3}{4}=4(n+1)*\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}; $$

collecting all terms in your expression, we arrive at

$$\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}+\frac{4(n+1)^3}{4}=n^2*\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}+4(n+1)*\frac{(n+1)^2}{4} =\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}*[n^2+4(n+1)],$$

as desired.

Comment: Thanks Avitus and Zev, I now understand

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE

Answer (score 2):

This is just the distributive property: for any numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, we have that
$$a\times(b+c)=(a\times b)+(a\times c).$$
In your case, you have
$$a=\frac{(n+1)^2}{4},\qquad b=n^2,\qquad c=4(n+1).$$
Note that
$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\times n^2=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4},$$
and also that
$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}\times 4(n+1)=\frac{4(n+1)\times(n+1)^2}{4}=\frac{4(n+1)^3}{4}$$
which can be simplified further to $(n+1)^3$.